# why history api pushstate stops working

Tags: javascript, php, html, pushstate, html5-history

This is my code:

```
onclick home button=`history.pushState({}, "Home", "/home");`

onclick settings button=`history.pushState({}, "Settings", "/settings");`
```

Now, it works fine, script works fine, but, when i add/append in address bar anything for example `t`, it would be `localhost/homet`, history api immediately stops working, I mean it works maybe but when I click some button for example when I click on settings button, url stays like before `localhost/homet` nothing is changed. why? is it possible to change that? maybe to remove? replace? anything? i tried to find out wheres problem but i couldn't. thanks

Comment: What does your browser console say?

Comment: @ceejayoz absolutely nothing

Comment: I don't understant your syntaxe. in HTML the syntaxe is <button onclick='history.pushState({}, "Settings", "/settings")' >my button </button>

Comment: @bormat no this example is just here to show you whats going on